# Transforming/mapping pandas column with several unique non-adjacent integers into a column with ascending adjacent integers (1,2,3, ,,,)

Tags: pandas

I would like to transform pandas column in an elegant and general way:
The data frame contains thousands of rows, but the column in question
has only 5-10 unique integer values. I would like to map/transform these unique
values into ascending sequence of adjacent integers. Like, if the unique values
are e.g., 10, 122, 350, 3, 27, I would like a transformation

```
    3->1 
    10->2 
    27->3 
    122->4 
    350->5
```

but I would like the solution to work for arbitrary number and set of unique
values, do not want to hard-wire the mapping.

I tried using apply, map, and cut methods without success ...

Comment: `df.groupby("column_in_question").ngroup().add(1)` ?

Comment: @Timeless rather factorize, `groupby` will sort the groups by default: `pd.factorize(df['col'])[0]+1`

Comment: I think that the values are not sorted. That's why I proposed `groupby` with its default `sort=True`.

Comment: Factorizing will give `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` while OP need `[2, 4, 5, 1, 3]`, no ?

Comment: The first proposal (groupby) works flawlessly, thanks.